# Creating a personalization engine with php

Tags: php

I am new to php and I want to create an php engine which changes the web content of a webpage with PHP with the use of data in mysql. For example (changing the order of navigation links on a webpage with the order of highest click count) I am not sure how PHP will read the HTML file and change the elements in the HTML file and also output the HTML file with the changes. Is this possible?

Comment: I go a feeling you should start by googling for some PHP tutorials or by buying a book to get you started on PHP. Without basic knowledge you will not be able to do anything useful, no matter what answers come up on this question.

Comment: Thanks, but I really just want an idea of what the code will look like since I do understand the coding. I mean I am not sure if you have to use fopen() function to read or any other way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure why you would want to generate the html, read it, change it and then output it. It seems to be a lot easier to just generate it the way you want to in the first place.

> I am not sure how PHP will read the HTML file and change the elements in the HTML file and also output the HTML file with the changes. Is this possible?

You could use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> $html = file_get_contents($url);

Then use a html-parser [like Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), change what you want to do and output it.

Comment: Thank you i should look at that. And im thinking I have to do this because I want to create an ENGINE. As in I also want to add other things such as increasing the font size of the link that has the most clicks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify HTML structure, use [ganon - HTML DOM parser for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/ganon/)

```
 include('path/ganon.php');

 // Parse the google code website into a DOM
 $html = file_get_dom('http://code.google.com/');

 foreach($html('p[class]') as $element) {
   echo $element->class, "<br>\n"; 
 }
```